# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present in spring 4.3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ng-file-upload

I am using spring 4.3.1 and I am going to upload file using ng-file-upload library.
this is my javascript code and when I connect the javascript code to php server, it works well.

```
        var promise = Upload.upload({
            url: url + "upload",
            method: 'POST',
            file: file,
            ignoreLoadingBar: true
        }).success(function(response) {
            flatForm.jsonForm = response.jsonForm;
            flatForm.xmlForm = response.xmlForm;
        }).error(function(response) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('veil:hide', {});
        });
```

And I appended commons-io-2.4.0.0.jar and commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar in /web-inf/lib folder.
e
And I added multipartResolver in applicationContext.xml file.

```
 <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
</bean>
```

And this is my controller class.

```
    @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    if (file == null || file.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("No file was sent.");
    }
}
```

But when I upload a file, I get such error.

```
Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
```

How can I fix this?
Please help me.
thank you for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to your specify the parameter file name must be `file` in your controller method,but you do not set it in your client code

Two ways to solve it:

a.  remove `@RequestParam("file")` to avoid specify the parameter name

b. add `name` property to your file element similar to below:

```
   <input type='file' name='file'>
```

Comment: so should I remove @RequestParam("file") or add name property to your file element ?

Comment: @alexKruts depends on yourself,you can try either of them

Comment: @alexKruts so try method a

Comment: then the file parameter is null.

Comment: @alexKruts now the error disappers and you need to check your client code,it works fine in php server does not mean it will work fine in java server

Comment: yes, so I fixed the client code as you pointed.But it has same issue.so I think it is java problem